# JQuery Validation is making me pull my hair out?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Please, someone, anyone. I've been having JQuery validation issues for the last few days. I've tried all kinds of things and even started from scratch a few times. This is my latest iteration using the link below as reference. What am I doing wrong?!

It gets to this line and stops: var validator = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("#formRegister", rules, messages);

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/jQueryValidateExample.aspx

HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Website.Pages.register" %>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../Styles/registration.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/val.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/_plugins/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="page">
<form runat="server" id="formRegister"><div>
<span id="Run">Username</span><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="rUsername" name="rUsername" /></div>
    <div><span id="Re">Email</span><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="rEmail" name="rEmail" /></div>
    <div><span id="Rce">Confirm Email</span><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="rConfirmEmail" /></div>
    <div><span id="Rpw">Password</span><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="rPassword" TextMode="Password" /></div>
    <div><span id="Rcpw">Confirm Password</span><br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="rConfirmPassword" TextMode="Password" Class="required"  /></div>
    <div id="buttonRegister"><input type="button" id="rRegister" value="Register" /></div>
</form>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function () {
// register.aspx
var rules = {
    rUsername: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
    },
    rEmail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    }
};
var messages = {
    rUsername: {
        required: "- Required",
        minlength: " - Minimum Length: 3"
    },
    rEmail: {
        required: "- Required",
        email: "- Incorrect Format"
    }
};
$("#rRegister").click(function () {
    var validator = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("#formRegister", rules, messages);
    if (!validator.validate())
        return;

    alert("Validation Success!");
});

});
```

Comment: What exactly are your _issues_?

Comment: Please specify how it is going wrong.

Comment: When you view source do the ID's match those used in your jquery?

Comment: I have a hunch it's because the `ID`s of the server-side controls are being altered when rendered (with their container's prefix), hence breaking the messages and rules. Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @raklos: They match. The plugin supposedly goes by the name attribute. 
<input id="rUsername" type="text" name="rUsername">

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: I'm using 4.0.

Comment: In your debugger does the Console come up with any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are correct.  Try this:

```
$("#rRegister").click(function () {
    var validator = new jQueryValidatorWrapper("#<%= formRegister.ClientID%>", rules, messages);
    if (!validator.validate())
        return;

    alert("Validation Success!");
});
```

Comment: No change unfortunately. Still stops in the same spot. "jQueryValidatorWrapper is not defined"

Comment: It looks like in the example there is a validatorwrapper.js. Dammit. I was hoping to do it with just the validate.js. Well, whatever works at this point I guess. Can't believe I didn't notice that. Grr!